# JS fetch-api - hangs for ~3 minutes when run from emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, fetch-api

I have a react native mobile app, that is using a "fetch" javascript function. When used from real (Android/iPhone) phone, it does work without any issue. However, when run from an Android emulator (for example Android Studio - Pixel 3 API 31), it hangs for 3-5 minutes before actually calling the request. At the end, the request is called sucessfully and response is also returned & read successfully.

Tried different hosts, methods, options, but same result all the time. Also tried different emulated "phones" and Android versions.

Application is build and deployed by npm 8.15.0 + metro 0.73.7

For example

```
await fetch("https://www.stackoverflow.com", {
    method: 'GET'
});
```

What might be the reason?

It shouldn't be performance related - the application is otherwise really responsive. No signs of any performance issues.